# Implications of granting exec rights to user

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-apps

When deploying a Google app script, there are two options for execution rights, One is to execute as the owner of the project

> Execute the app as: me@gmail.com
>   You need to authorize the script before distributing the URL

or user accessing the web app

> Execute the app as: User accessing the 
>   web app Users will be asked to
>   authorize the script.

I would like to know what implications does allowing the app to execute under the users identity as opposed to my identity. There really isn't any sensitive or private data being passed around in this specific script, but for some reason the dev who wrote it, set it to execute under his identity and it's causing problems. I would like to know what are the dangers of allowing the script to execute under the user, taking into consideration that the app can only be accessed by people belonging to a specific domain.

Comment: You stated that the setting is causing problems.  What problems?

Comment: Who owns the data that the app is accessing?

Comment: @SandyGood It's an authorization problem. The app won't load. I believe the owner might have to reauthorize the script from within the editor by running doGet(). Thing is, the account was deactivated and I am unable to make any changes to the project itself.

Answer (score 0):

If each user of the Apps Script is *only* accessing their **own** data, then you could change the setting.  But if there is centralized data that lots of users are accessing, then somehow they need access.  Either the data would need to be set to be shared, or the Apps Script needs to run under the authority of who owns the data.  It's better to have the Apps Script run under the authority of the person who owns the data, then make the data public to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the app run as the user, then the user can access only his google resources. For example if your script writes a new file to google drive, it will make a new file in the user's google drive account. Another example is sending email - the script will send email from the user's address.
Each user in this scenario must first authorize permissions for the script/

However, if you have the script run as the owner who wrote the script, then the script has access to the owner resources (and in this example, will write a new file to the owner's google drive account, or send email from the owner's address). In this option all the users can get access to work on the same resource.
The owner in this scenario is the only one required to authorize permissions for the script.